# Google + OAuth cannot be used after March 7, 2019

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-plus

I have received an email from GoogleDevelopers-noreply@google.com stating that Google + OAuth cannot be used after March 7, 2019, does this also apply to OAuth in Firebase? And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly which OAuth you're using.

If you are using any of the Google+ scopes specifically (these all include the word "plus" in them), then you will need to migrate away from using these.

If you are not, you should be fine.

If you are unsure, there should be a table in your email that specifies why it thinks you're using the Google+ APIs, and you may wish to update your question to include that table and we can help.